# Prepend to the title tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, page-title

I want to have my title tag look like this:

`My Website - Name of Page`

I want to prepend the `My Website -` part so that I don't have to type it on every new page I make. So the title tag that I actually have on the page would be:

```
<title>Name of Page</title>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This is what view templates are for.

Comment: Also, users will appreciate it if you use `Name of Page - Name of Website` instead of the other way around - that way you can actually see which tab is which when the titles are cut off.

Comment: @Dav: Good idea. Will definatly do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a jquery script to do it would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    document.title = "Your WebSite Name - " + document.title; 
});
```

I would recommend doing this at the page level instead of client side though...

Comment: Didn't think it would be this simple, but ok. ;-)

Comment: 2/3 of those lines (the jQuery ones) are unnecessary

Comment: I gave you the accepted answer solely because it made your rep a nicer number ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Seems others have tried and not been able to do is using jQuery but you can use `document.title`, http://hancic.info/change-page-title-with-jquery